# spring boot gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

In my Spring boot gradle project when I am running the project as springboot run then the ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames() is giving 384 beans but when I run the project in executable jar file then ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames() is giving 334 beans name only. The beans it seems to be skiped are in application-context.xml file. thanks

Comment: Are there any arguments in spring boot run that are not being passed to the executable jar?

Comment: no, the files are read from @PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"}) and resource is imported with @ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext-common.xml"})

Comment: One more important thing to mention is that the beans which are not created is seems to be part of an external jar which I am extending in my class. and if I create the same beans using java code under @Bean it is working fine.

Comment: It worked when I changed the name of my xml to Beans.xml thanks.